# Cordova plugins stop working when loading another html file

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, plugins

Yes, I researched whole stackoverflow but could not find a (working) solution to my problem.

I made an application (game) using **Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.1**. I use several plugins which are loaded and fine when the first page (index.html) loads. onDeviceReady fires and everything is OK.

However, when I use

**window.location.href = "anotherpage.html"**

all plugins become "**undefined**". For example:

- console
- window.plugins.AdMob (which works perfectly and install ads, BTW, but is inaccessible later)
- navigator.notification
- window.plugins.socialsharing

But the plugins used are not important - **EVERYTHING** becomes **undefined** when new page loads, meaning that plugins are lost.

So I can not use plugins in subsequent pages of the application. This happens on both Android and iOS on any tested device. Concerning message which can be viewed in XCode log output is "**Resetting plugins due to page load**". I searched all stackoverflow resources related to this message but found no relation to this problem (except one regarding IFRAME load which did not help either).

Can anyone help me to get my plugins work again when I load another html file inside Cordova application?

Thanks in advance!

Davor

Comment: try `document.location` instead of `window.location.href` make sure you put cordova.js in every html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to inherit the cordova.js file in every html-document.

Comment: Actually, brauchle_andi is right. I figured out that cordova.js changes it's location when build is done - it comes to root, not js folder. Many thanks this pointed me to the location of the problem!